# How to get 'base theme' information about a theme?

Tags: 8

In an admin settings form in a custom module, I need to determine what base themes a specific theme uses (the default theme, not the current theme). If I know the child theme's name, how do I obtain the names of the 'base themes' that child theme uses (if any)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the details of a theme by using [ThemeHandler::listInfo()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Extension!ThemeHandler.php/function/ThemeHandler%3A%3AlistInfo/8.2.x).

```
$child_theme = 'bartik';

$base_theme = \Drupal::service('theme_handler')->listInfo()[$child_theme]->base_theme;

$base_themes = \Drupal::service('theme_handler')->listInfo()[$child_theme]->base_themes;
```